# Create WiFi 6(E) hotspot / access point

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, nmcli, wifi-hotspot

Is there a way to create a WiFi 6(E) hotspot (or AccessPoint) in Ubuntu (or Linux in general).
I was previously using `nmcli` but it only supports `a` and `bg` but because I use an Intel AX210 I would like to create an `802.11ax` hotspot - is this possible?

Comment: From what I've heard the Intel AX210 cannot work as an AP for any channels rather than 2.4GHz: https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/10u76li/hostapd_with_wifi_6e_card/

Comment: As for `hostapd` it supports Wi-Fi 6, not sure about 6E, using `hw_mode=ad`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Intel-AX210-can-t-create-6GHz-hotspot/m-p/1230782 "Mobile hotspot is supported by Intel® Wi-Fi 6E AX210 in legacy bands 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz."

Comment: *in legacy bands 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz* - cool, that means it won't work as a 6(E) AP.